# Can I find how much a patent holder received in royalties for making it available under licence?

Tags: royalties, valuation, value

I want to find out how much a specific patent holder has drawn in royalties on the licence for a particular patent.

Is this possible?

I realise where a company's accounts are public, I can identify their total royalty income, but not from a specific patent grant. (Unless they have a sole patent, of course.)

If you were trying to understand the economic value of a particular patent, how would you go about it?

Comment: I fear even with public companies such information would likely be confidential.

Comment: This would be very hard to get and is probably off topic. I know that economists and others have tried to value patents. I would look in google scholar for some acedemic papers.

Comment: Many thanks. Assumed as much.

Answer (score 0):

There are two different and very distinct questions there. Please separate them.

First is: how much licensing royalties have actually been paid.

Second is: If you were trying to understand the economic value of a particular patent, how would you go about it?

For the first, I can't imagine any honest way of doing it. As a dishonest way, you could make an offer to buy it from the owner, and find out what they demand. Or do the reverse and call the licensing party and pretend that you have a substitute for that invention.

For the second: I was actually the engineer interviewer at Google, at a time when they were hiring people to acquire patents. I asked a variant of your question to the candidates, and as far as I can remember, everyone had a different answer. "$300,000 per patent" is a rule of thumb. They are worth much less than you probably think.